# Duplicate interface definition for class 'TfliteFlutterHelperPlusPlugin'

Tags: flutter

That's where the error occurred:

````
**tflite_flutter_helper_plus-Swift.h**
```
    SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC26tflite_flutter_helper_plus29TfliteFlutterHelperPlusPlugin")
```
**TfliteFlutterHelperPlusPlugin.m**

```
    @implementation TfliteFlutterHelperPlusPlugin
    + (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar {
      [SwiftTfliteFlutterHelperPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
}
```

**flutter doctor**
>[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 3.13.9 on channel stable at /Users/a2289/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d211f42860 (3 months ago), 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
    • Engine revision 0545f8705d
    • Dart version 3.1.5
    • DevTools version 2.25.0
>
>[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/a2289/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
>
>[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0
>
>[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
>[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
>
>[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0`your text`
>
>[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • PNC_B1_TEST_2.4G (mobile) • 00008101-000104910001401E • ios            • iOS 16.7 20H19
    • macOS (desktop)           • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.216
>
>[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
>
>• No issues found!
````

Is it better to use `tflite` package than `tflite_flutter`?

Wanted to run, but failed.